# pandas dataframe merge overlapping keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, left and right. The keys (columns) of right are a subset of those in left. I want to to keep the column data from right and put in left, and I don't care about the overlapping key data in the left:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['Knan', 'Knan', 'Knan', 'Knan'],
                  'key2': ['Kxx1', 'Kxx2', 'Kxx3', 'Kxx4'],
                  'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})


right = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
                   'key2': ['K5', 'K6', 'K7', 'K8']})

for key in right.keys():
    if key in left.keys():
        left[key] = right[key]
```

Is there a better way to do this with merge or concat or something?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df_out = right.combine_first(left)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    A   B key1 key2
0  A0  B0   K0   K5
1  A1  B1   K1   K6
2  A2  B2   K1   K7
3  A3  B3   K2   K8
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely does it.

Comment: I did upvote, but as I have < 15 points it won't show it. And I'm not sure I can formally accept it either, based on my newness